# 2 while loop to read contents of a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have 2 file.  Let's say file1 and file2.  I want to read the file1 together with the file2 so it will give me an output into one single line.

eg. file1 = contents "123.45.67.89"
    file2 = contents "hostname.cco"

output:    123.45.67.89  hostname.cco

Im runninng nested loop but seems I can not accoumplish what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually quite simple, but it does require reading from more than one file descriptor. Essentially, you set up a read loop, as normal, and redirect a file to `fd3` and a second file on `stdin`, you can then read independent lines from each file on each iteration of the loop. (e.g. read line1 from file1, line1 from file2, and so on). You can use:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r -u 3 linea; do               ## reads linea from file1
    read -r lineb;                         ## reads lineb from file2
    printf "%s %s\n" "$linea" "$lineb"     ## outputs combined lines
done 3<"$1" <"$2"  ## notice first file on fd3 and 2nd on stdin

exit 0
```

**Example Use/Output**

Then using your file content for `file1` and `file2`, you would get the following output:

```
$ bash read2fd.sh file1 file2
123.45.67.89 hostname.cco
```

If that is not what you intended, please let me know and I'm happy to help further.